# Do I repeat the sunnah azkar of sleeping if I wake up in the night?

Tags: sunnah

Before I go to sleep I follow the sunnah by reading ayat AL kursi, falaq, then Nas.

If I wake up in the middle of the night for tahhajud, then go back to sleep for Fajr, do I have to repeat ayat AL kursi, falaq, and Nas again?

Comment: It is sunnah not fard.

Comment: Yeah but do I have to do it everytime as in if I wake up 50 times a night would that mean I have to do it everytime or is once sufficient for the whole night

Comment: Fard is something you are required to do. Sunnah is of two types but w.r.t ur question sunnah is optional. If you are able to do regularly once before going to sleep, you have inshallah done your azkhar.

Comment: Also you can add the following or learn them in future as azkhar before sleep: Surah Fatiha, Surah Ikhlas, Surah Falaq, Surah Nas, Surah Kafirun, Ayatul Kursi, Last 2 ayah of Surah baqarah, and Tasbih Fatima (33 time Alhamdullah, 33 time Subhanallah, 34 time Allah Akbar) .... once your imaan is stronger and you have a better grasp on Quran, you can also recite Surah Mulk before sleeping

Comment: What I meant by the question is: will the protection stl be there if I wake up at 2 am and go back to sleep at 3? Or do I have to read the surahs again

Comment: Doing it once inshallah will suffice

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to think about these little/non obligatory things such way.
If you find it comfortable and easy, do it, otherwise don't put yourself in hardship.

Following is Hadith for your satisfaction.

> Narrated `Abdullah:
>
> The Prophet (Peace be upon him) fasted for days continuously; the
>   people also did the same but it was difficult for them. So, the
>   Prophet (Peace be upon him) forbade them (to fast continuously for
>   more than one day). They slid, "But you fast without break (no food
>   was taken in the evening or in the morning)." The Prophet (Peace be
>   upon him) replied, "I am not like you, for I am provided with food and
>   drink (by Allah).
>
> Sahih al-Bukhari 1922

Answer (score 0):

most authentic opinion is that doing it once suffices you for the whole night

Comment: Try to bring more explanation and evidence to back up your answer and you can take your time to read on [tour] and [answer] for more information